# Finding % of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentage, subtotal

This is what my table looks like

```
Measure    PT Name
Expired    Mickey Mouse
Expired    Donald Duck
Alive      Big Bird
Alive      Baby Bird
Rehab      Daffy Duck
Xray       Goofy
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Measure   Count  %
Expired   15     40%
Alive     5      13%
Rehab     7      18%
Xray      10     27%
```

---

I made a mistake, I want to get a count grouped by `Measure` including a % all in the same SQL statement

```
Select DischargeDisp, Count(*) as TotalCnt
INTO #Measure
from #LOS
group by DischargeDisp
```

Comment: Is this in Excel? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, this is in SQL

Comment: What do you have so far by way of sql statement?

Comment: I have the first part but I cannot seem to get the grouping of the Measure with the %

Comment: I also have the grouping by Measure but I want to include the % at the same time

Comment: I'm looking to see if there;s a way I can do it without 3 select statements

Comment: Did the question change significantly after some answers were posted?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted ?

```
Select Measure, Count(*), Count(*) * 100 / SUM ( COUNT (*) ) OVER()
from   #LOS
group by Measure
```

Comment: This provided me the % but I want to also have a count of DischargeDisp

Comment: added count(*) to the query

Answer (score 0):

```
select Measure
      ,SUM(m_count) m_count
      ,(sum(m_count)*100/(select sum(m_count) from your_table)) as Percentage
      from your_table group by Measure;
```

Changed column name `count` to `m_count`. As it creates confusion.

Comment: I made a mistake, I don't have a column name m_count or count

Comment: I want to get the m_count and also the %

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Measure,
       SUM(Cnt) AS [Count],
       CAST(SUM(Cnt) * 100 / (SELECT SUM(Cnt) FROM #LOS) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%' AS [%]
FROM #LOS
GROUP BY Measure
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions keeps changing but maybe this will meet your need:

```
Select Measure, Sum(1) as 'Count', LTrim(Str(Sum(1) * 100 / (Select Count(*) From Measure))) + '%' as [Percent]
  from Measure
  Group by Measure
order by Measure
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
select distinct Measure, 
       count(*) over (partition by measure) as [Count],
       format(convert(float,count(*) over (partition by measure)) /count(*) over(),'p') as [%]
from los
```

test is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7be45/3)